# If I have a catch exception will everything be caught, even with COM object?

Tags: c#, iis, com

I have noticed in production that our IIS app dies (app pool shutdown) and when this does happen I see an error in the COM object that our application uses. It happens infrequently so it is difficult to debug what is causing the error.

I have put a try...catch(Exception e){} block around the COM code and I was wondering if this random COM  object is not being caught.

Is it this possible? In other words if the COM exception occurs it will be caught?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will catch it with

```
try
{
    //code here
}
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException COMex)
{
    //you can try this too. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898726/why-would-this-catch-all-block-not-in-fact-catch-all
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //do things
}
```

You can check the [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation about the exception and see that inherits `System.Exception`

Comment: This is not always the case.  OP can easily be throwing an error that is not caught in a try catch.

Comment: @paqogomez obviously if he throws this exception somewhere, the code should be in try catch ... If it is not in try catch the exception will be not catch ...

Comment: My understanding from OP is a situation like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10853702/2589202) where memory errors  are thrown.